# What is the command to flash a NIC link light?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line-interface, hardware, nic

I remember using a command line tool to flash a NIC's link light to identify it. I can't remember for the life of me what it was.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yeah it was ethtool I was looking for but specifically this will flash the link light for two minutes:

```
ethtool -p eth0 120
```

Comment: it will blink activity led ( orange) or link light (green)?

Comment: may vary based on NIC but for the ones I tested it flashed the link light

Answer (score 35):

Is [ethtool](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ethtool) what you're looking for

```
ethtool --identify eth0
```

Answer (score 3):

Ethtool also works with vmware ESXi with -p parameter:

Example: `ethtool -p vmnic0 15`

vmnic0 will blink for 15 seconds

Here is a video that shows how it works (at 2:50 shows blink):

http://www.sysadmit.com/2017/06/vmware-esxi-vmnic-nic-fisica.html